# invalid syntax on =?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am a beginner at python trying to make a very simple program using yes/no. it says that there is a syntax error on the first = in the line:

```
if monkeya="yes" and monkeyb="yes":
```

here's my entire code.

```
monkeya=input("is monkey A smiling? (yes or no) ")
monkeyb=input("is monkey B smiling? (yes or no) ")

if monkeya="yes" and monkeyb="yes":
   print("unsafe - plotting")

elif monkeya="no" and monkeyb="no":
   print("unsafe - angry")

else:
   print("safe")
```

Comment: Use double `=`: `if monkeya=="yes"...`

Answer (score 7):

Equality test requires a *double* `==`, you used single `=`:

```
if monkeya=="yes" and monkeyb=="yes":
   print("unsafe - plotting")

elif monkeya=="no" and monkeyb=="no":
   print("unsafe - angry")
```

A single `=` equals sign is an assignment statement, which you cannot use inside of an expression (so not after `if`).

Answer (score 4):

You should use double equals sign on comparing two values:

```
if monkeya == "yes" and monkeyb == "yes":
```